# How to resume watching a YouTube playlist from where I left off?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I am watching a playlist which is a lecture series. In between the video or when a particular video is finished. I close the browser. How can I return to the playlist from where I last stopped?

Ideally, one would look up the video in history and start there... but I don't think that gives the expected result. It does not resume the playlist, per se.

Answer (score 2):

There's no builtin way to do that, I think the closer would be to go to the playlist page and check the first video which you haven't finished watching, or the next to watch.

For example, here, you can see that until 3.6 all the video are watched, 4.1 isn't, and 4.2 only a bit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can always assemble it manually. By looking at URL, you can notice that it's build from 4 parts:

**<kbd>ADDRESS MASK</kbd> <kbd>PLAYLIST ID</kbd> <kbd>VIDEO ID</kbd> <kbd>INDEX NUMBER</kbd>**

For example, to start from 34th video from a given playlist:

**<kbd>https://youtu.be//watch?</kbd> <kbd>&list=PL5Qevr-CpW_yZZjYspehnFc-QRKQMCKHB</kbd> <kbd>&v=1nzx7O7ndfI</kbd> <kbd>&index=34</kbd>**

**https://www.youtube.com/watch?&list=PL5Qevr-CpW_yZZjYspehnFc-QRKQMCKHB&v=1nzx7O7ndfI&index=34**

**playlist ID**, **video ID** and **index number** can be put in any order you wish. Also, in the first item after **address mask** you can omit the **&** character. **Shuffle** button should be set to off for ultimate  chronological playback experience.

Comment: This only works if you already know the video ID of the item you want to watch...

Answer (score 0):

When I didn't find any solution I made one for myself.

You can check it here
https://plist.abdel-alim.com

```
It's still in beta, if you have any feedback please share it.
```

Comment: Hi Abdel,  why does your app not load the full playlist? Otherwise it is briiliant ....

Comment: For example, check https://plist.abdel-alim.com/watch?playlist=PLB2vhKMBjSxMK8YelHj6VS6w3KxuKsMvT, and check the same playlist on Youtube, the number of videos is not matching...

Comment: Could it be that the videos are not public?
I'll check that out @IshraaqParvez

Comment: I think it's a limit on Youtube's API
I didn't think they had such limitations :thinking_face:
I hope Youtube allows a way around that limit
Thanks for letting me know man

Answer (score -1):

It's easy and you don't need a special website.  Open the playlist and watch videos. Drag the address to your favorites or bookmarks bar before closing out when you're done.  When you want to go back, open the link.  You will be at the last video you watched.  Throw out that bookmark and save a new bookmark at the end of your session.  Repeat.